# Parse de string para array em PHP

Tags: php, parse

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
/dev/sda1      ext4      19620732  16936800   1664184
udev           devtmpfs     10240     10240         0
tmpfs          tmpfs       101232     96740      4492
tmpfs          tmpfs       253080    253080         0
tmpfs          tmpfs         5120      5120         0
tmpfs          tmpfs       253080    253080         0
var 89www        vboxsf   487350400 350068644 137281756
```

Desejo passar a string em questão para array, de modo que a estrutura final seja:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sistArq] => /dev/sda1
            [tipo] => ext4
            [tamanho] => 19620732
            [disponivel] => 16936800
            [usado] => 1664184
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sistArq] => udev
            [tipo] => devtmpfs
            [tamanho] => 10240
            [disponivel] => 10240
            [usado] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sistArq] => tmpfs
            [tipo] => tmpfs
            [tamanho] => 101232
            [disponivel] => 96740
            [usado] => 4492
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sistArq] => tmpfs
            [tipo] => tmpfs
            [tamanho] => 253080
            [disponivel] => 253080
            [usado] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sistArq] => tmpfs
            [tipo] => tmpfs
            [tamanho] => 5120
            [disponivel] => 5120
            [usado] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sistArq] => tmpfs
            [tipo] => tmpfs
            [tamanho] => 253080
            [disponivel] => 253080
            [usado] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [sistArq] => var 89www
            [tipo] => vboxsf
            [tamanho] => vboxsf
            [disponivel] => 487350400
            [usado] => 350068644
        )

)
```

Tentei algo como:

```
$output = trim(preg_replace('/^.+\n/', '', $string));
$output = explode("\n", $output);
$output = preg_replace('/[ ]{1,}/', ' == ' ,$output);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($output); $i++)
{
    $campos = explode(" == ", $output[$i]);

    $arr[$i] = array(
                'sistArq' => $campos[0],
                'tipo' => $campos[1],
                'tamanho' => $campos[2],
                'disponivel' => $campos[3],
                'usado' => $campos[4]
                );
}
```

Porém, não tive o sucesso esperado.

Comment: Nesse caso me parece mais fácil usar substring do que RegEx. Aliás, as colunas podem não ser fixas dependendo do tamanho das informações listadas, mas seria o caso de dar uma olhada nas flags do comando para ver quais afetam a formatação de saída (por exemplo, forçar formato Posix, essas coisas)

Comment: as colunas são separadas por um tab? se for he so ler cada linha  com um explode \n ou \r e em cada linha vc da um explode para o tab

Comment: detalhe a geração desse arquivo na sua pergunta?

Comment: Esse output vem do terminal Linux, as colunas são separados por espaço. Sendo que a primeira coluna possui vários espaços como separador, as demais pode ter somente 1 espaço ou vários sequencialmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deveria funcionar:

```
$string = "/dev/sda1      ext4      19620732  16936800   1664184\n" .
          "udev           devtmpfs     10240     10240         0\n" .
          "tmpfs          tmpfs       101232     96740      4492\n" .
          "tmpfs          tmpfs       253080    253080         0\n" .
          "tmpfs          tmpfs         5120      5120         0\n" .
          "tmpfs          tmpfs       253080    253080         0\n" .
          "var 89www        vboxsf   487350400 350068644 137281756";

$arr = [];

foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $string) as $line){
    preg_match("/^([\/\w\d ]+) +([\w\d]+) +(\d+) +(\d+) +(\d+)$/", $line, $campos);

    $arr[] = [
        'sistArq' => trim($campos[1]),
        'tipo' => $campos[2],
        'tamanho' => $campos[3],
        'disponivel' => $campos[4],
        'usado' => $campos[5]
        ];
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: um dos itens não é carregado, são 7 e devido a linha que tem `/` ele ignora!!!. tem que ter um ajuste!

Comment: Obrigado, fiz a modificação.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz a lógica ao inverso pegando o [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array.php) de ***trás pra frente*** e quando limite de colunas era ***igual a 4***, o resto tudo é da chave `sistArq`. Nessa função passe o diretório e nome de arquivo com extensão.

[***Exemplo Funcional***](http://ideone.com/fork/lkOi2e)

***Função buscando um variável do tipo texto:***

```
$txt = "/dev/sda1      ext4      19620732  16936800   1664184
        udev           devtmpfs     10240     10240         0
        tmpfs          tmpfs       101232     96740      4492
        tmpfs          tmpfs       253080    253080         0
        tmpfs          tmpfs         5120      5120         0
        tmpfs          tmpfs       253080    253080         0
        var 89www adadfaas       vboxsf   487350400 350068644 137281756";

function parse_file_terminal_linux_string($txt)
{
    $ponteiro = explode("\n", $txt);
    foreach ($ponteiro as $key => $value) 
    {
        $values = explode(" ", $value);     
        $keys = array('usado','disponivel','tamanho','tipo','sistArq'); 
        for($i = count($values); $i >=0 ; $i--)
        {
            if (!empty($values[$i]))
            {
                if (count($keys)>0) 
                    $c = array_shift($keys);                        
                $result[$key][$c] = ($c === 'sistArq' && isset($result[$key][$c])) 
                    ? $result[$key][$c]." ".trim($values[$i])
                    : trim($values[$i]);
            }
        }
        $result[$key]['sistArq'] =
            implode(" ", array_reverse(explode(" ",$result[$key]['sistArq'])));
    }   
    return $result; 
}
```

***Função buscando um arquivo de texto:***

```
function parse_file_terminal_linux($name = "arq.txt")
{
    $ponteiro = file($name);
    foreach ($ponteiro as $key => $value) 
    {
        $values = explode(" ", $value);     
        $keys = array('usado','disponivel','tamanho','tipo','sistArq'); 
        for($i = count($values); $i >=0 ; $i--)
        {
            if (!empty($values[$i]))
            {
                if (count($keys)>0) 
                    $c = array_shift($keys);                        
                $result[$key][$c] = ($c === 'sistArq' && isset($result[$key][$c])) 
                    ? $result[$key][$c]." ".trim($values[$i])
                    : trim($values[$i]);
            }
        }
        $result[$key]['sistArq'] =
            implode(" ", array_reverse(explode(" ",$result[$key]['sistArq'])));
    }   
    return $result; 
}

print_r(parse_file_terminal_linux("files/arq.txt"));
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi do código você está lendo o array, porém, eu quero transformar a string em array. Com excessão da primeira coluna, todas as demais não possuem espaço entre seus caracteres, logo eu preciso criar alguma lógica que me permita pegar os valores das colunas e gerar um array, sendo que o delimitador comum será o espaço. O total de colunas será sempre igual a 4

Comment: @Fábio, fiz a edição a função são igualzinhas, o que mudou é que um lê um texto com quebra de linha **("\n")** e o outro um arquivo também com quebra de linha. Espero ter ajudado! O número de colunas são 5 e a ultima pode ter espaços, antes de mais nada teste os exemplos das duas resposta e utilize para você a melhor.